# Pycharm - Disable 'Local variable 'xxx' might be referenced before assignment'

Tags: python, pycharm, warnings, intellij-inspections

In pycharm, I would like to disable the following inspection warn:
"Local variable 'xxx' might be referenced before assignment" but I can't find it in settings/inspections.

PS: This is not a duplicate, as I understand this warn. I am just asking how to disable it in pycharm.

Update: Please find below an example of what I mean

```
cond = True
def add1(x):
    return x+1
if cond:
    a = 1
if cond:
    b = add1(a) # the warn is on the 'a'
```

Solution:

"Unbound local variable" inspection. (cf. Lomtrur answer below)

Comment: are you using a global variable `xxx`? what causes this warning?

Comment: no, it's a local variable. In a main(),  `if cond : var =fct1()`  and later  `fct2(var)` shows this warn. But I don't care, that's my coding style.

Comment: What happens if you click after the `a` and press Alt+Enter? That should tell you which inspection you want to disable, or does that not work? What is your PyCharm version?

Comment: It was the "Unbound local variable" inspection. Thanks for this method Lomtrur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the cursor immediately after `a`. It should have a colored background or be underlined to show that this is where the warning is. Then press `Alt+Enter` to open the context menu. This should show you what the inspection is and also give the option to disable it. (PyCharm 2018.2.5 Professional Edition)

Comment: Great. Solution is "Unbound local variable" inspection. Thanks for your method, I also learned to fish.

Comment: Also, this method, as well as the code analysis method, are both described [in the documentation section on suppressing inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/suppressing-inspections.html). If you're not aware of the code analysis method, I'd check it out as it can be powerful too.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work consistently on the newer versions.

Answer (score 13):

You can disable it locally by putting the following comment on the line preceding the warning:

`# noinspection PyUnboundLocalVariable`

It will only apply to that instance.

If you put that bit of code right before the function or method declaration, it will suppress the message for the entire function or method.

In your case

```
if cond:
    # noinspection PyUnboundLocalVariable
    b = add1(a)
```